# how can i filter the data based on array of cities

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vue.js, debugging, filtering

I have a select menu where i can select the city
I want to display all book available on this city ( based on array of cities )
what i should write inside checkavailablecity

here is the full code

[the full code](https://jsfiddle.net/3mryt8Lo/)

HTML :

```
<select>
<option value="NewYork" v-model="myCity">New York</option>
.. </select>
<ul>
<li v-for="book in checkavailablecity">{{book.bookName}} 
</li>
</ul></div>
```

JavaScript :

```
data: {
  myCity:'',
  bookinfo:[{
  bookName:'Big Nate: Fun Blaster',
  cities: ['NewYork','Washington','Texas']
  },
  {
  bookName:'Now I Rise',
  cities: ['Texas']
  }
  ]
},
computed: {
  checkavailablecity: function(){
       var mycity = this.myCity;
       return this.bookinfo.filter(function(book){
       ....
     })   }   } })
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you bind a variable to the select dropdown and not on each option.

So the `select` dropdown in the link you shared would change from:

```
<select>
 <option value="NewYork" v-model="myCity">New York</option>
 <option value="Texas" v-model="myCity">Texas</option>
</select>
```

to

```
<select v-model="myCity">
 <option value="NewYork" >New York</option>
 <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
</select>
```

---

Your callback function would simply check whether your `cities` for the current book has the current city selected. It would look like below:

```
return this.bookinfo.filter(function(book){
     return book.cities.includes(mycity);
})
```

**Working Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/k8L4my3u/